# Не верифицируется ssl от letsencrypt

Tags: docker, ssl, letsencrypt, traefik

Поднимаю службу контейнеров в докере.В качестве прокси выступает Traefik
Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true  
    volumes:
      - $PWD/wolumes/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - $PWD/wolumes/data/acme.json:/acme.json
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "443:443"  
    restart: unless-stopped 
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.10-alpine
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wolumes/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ${PWD}/wolumes/env/postgres.env
    restart: unless-stopped
  gogs:
    image: gogs/gogs
    container_name: gogs
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wolumes/gogs:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gogs.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gogs.rule=Host(`mydomain.xyz`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gogs.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.gogs.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.gogs-service.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"  
    ports: 
      - "8022:22"
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
  nexus:
    image: sonatype/nexus3 
    container_name: nexus
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wolumes/nexus-data:/nexus-data
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nexus.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nexus.rule=Host(`mydomain.xyz`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nexus.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nexus.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.nexus-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8081"  
    restart: unless-stopped    
  jenkins:
    image: tilk9092/jenkins_gogs:latest
    container_name: jenkins
    user: '1000'
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wolumes/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.jenkins.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.jenkins.rule=Host(`mydomain.xyz`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.jenkins.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.jenkins.tls.certresolver=letsEncrypt"
      - "traefik.http.services.jenkins-service.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"  
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  html:
  vho
```

Traefik.yml:

```
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

http:
  routers:
    http-catchall:
      rule: hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)
      entrypoints:
      - http
      middlewares:
      - redirect-to-https
  middlewares:
    redirect-to-https:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: false

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    
certificatesResolvers:
  letsEncrypt:
    acme:
      email: mymail@gmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

По итогу все службы запускаются,но браузеры ругаются на "Соединение не установлено: Вероятная угроза безопасности".Также показывает незащищенное соединение.
Идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно заменить caServer с "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" на "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).